# Sort and search column when I'm querying with findbysql in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm searching four tables and joined them and got the output I want. But unable to sort or filter the output. Please tell me how I can search it by district or a sell range or collection range.
PartiesSearch model is -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\districtreport\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Bills;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Payment;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;
$query = \Yii::$app->db;
/**
 * PartiesSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties`.
 */
class PartiesSearch extends Parties
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['party_id'], 'integer'],
            [['parties_partyname', 'address', 'parties_district', 'name_manager', 'transport', 'dlno', 'instruction', 'con', 'district','sale','sell','collection'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {

        $sql = 'select 
        tsell.district as district,
        tsell.totalsale as sell,
        coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection 
        from 
            (SELECT 
                district, 
                coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale 
            FROM `districts` 
            left join 
                (SELECT 
                    parties_district, 
                    billdate,
                    sum(billamount) as sale 
                FROM `bills` 
                left join parties on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname 
                group by parties_district) as sell 
            on sell.parties_district = districts.district) as tsell 
        left join 
            (SELECT 
                parties_district,
                payment_date,
                COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection 
            FROM `payment` 
            left join parties on payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname 
            group by parties_district) as tcollection 
               on tsell.district = tcollection.parties_district';
        $query = Parties::findBySql($sql);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            //'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['district'=>SORT_DESC]]
        ]);

        $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => [
                'sell' => [
                   'asc' => ['sell' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['sell' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'Sell'
                ],
                'collection' => [
                    'asc' => ['collection' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['collection' => SORT_DESC],      
                    'label' => 'Collection'
                ],      
                'district' => [
                    'asc' => ['tsell.district' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['tsell.district' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'District'
                ]                               
            ]
        ]);



        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'party_id' => $this->party_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parties_partyname', $this->parties_partyname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parties_district', $this->parties_district])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name_manager', $this->name_manager])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'transport', $this->transport])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'dlno', $this->dlno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'instruction', $this->instruction])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'con', $this->con])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sell', $this->sell])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'collection', $this->collection])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'district', $this->district]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Parties Model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\districtreport\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "parties".
 *
 * @property integer $party_id
 * @property string $parties_partyname
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $parties_district
 * @property string $name_manager
 * @property string $transport
 * @property string $dlno
 * @property string $instruction
 * @property string $con
 */
class Parties extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $sale;
    public $district;
    public $sell;
    public $collection;
    public $bills;
    public $partyname;
    public $billdate;

    //public $sale;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'parties';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['parties_partyname', 'parties_district', 'name_manager'], 'required'],
            [['parties_partyname'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['address', 'instruction'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['parties_district'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['name_manager', 'transport', 'dlno'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['con'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['parties_partyname'], 'unique'],
            [['name_manager'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Managers::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['name_manager' => 'manager_managername']],
            [['con'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Console::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['con' => 'console']],
            [['parties_district'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Districts::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['parties_district' => 'district']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'party_id' => 'Party ID',
            'parties_partyname' => 'Parties Partyname',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'parties_district' => 'Parties District',
            'name_manager' => 'Name Manager',
            'transport' => 'Transport',
            'dlno' => 'Dlno',
            'instruction' => 'Instruction',
            'con' => 'Con',
        ];
    }
    public function getDistricts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Districts::className(), ['district' => 'parties_district']);
    }
    public function getBills()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bills::className(), ['bills_partyname' => 'parties_partyname']);
    }
    public function getPayment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::className(), ['payment_partyname' => 'parties_partyname']);
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
//use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\ExpartiesSearch;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\districtreport\models\PartiesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Parties';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="parties-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<!--     <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Parties', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p> -->
    <!-- <div class="custom-filter">

    Date range:
     <input name="start" />
     <input name="end" />

    </div> -->


        <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'export' => false,
        'columns' => [
        [
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'detail' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                $searchModel = new ExpartiesSearch();
                $searchModel-> district = $model->district;
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_exparties', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);                   

                },
            ],
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


            'district',
            // [
            // 'attribute' => 'date',
            // 'value' => 'tsell.date',
            // 'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(['language' => 'ru', 'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy']),
            // 'format' => 'html',
            // ],           
            'sell',
            'collection',


            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

[image]
In this picture we can see that though the sell sort is there but it's not sorting the data actually.
[image]
In picture 2 we can see that though the data assam is passed to the next level of kartik expandrow, it's not filtering.

Comment: are you using `gridview`?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: what is in _exparties?

Comment: can I also see your action inside of your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql%28 code with findbysql cannot be sorted or filtered.
However, it can be sorderd by building query following page - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html
The query will be like -

```
$subQuery1 = (new Query())->select(['parties_district','billdate','sum(billamount) as sale'])->from ('parties')->join('LEFT JOIN','bills','bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname')->groupby('parties_district')->where('billdate != "NULL"');        
        $subQuery2 = (new Query())->select(['district','coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale'])->from('districts')->leftJoin(['sell' => $subQuery1],'sell.parties_district = districts.district'); 
        $subQuery3 = (new Query())->select(['parties_district','payment_date','COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection'])->from('payment')->join('LEFT JOIN','parties','payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname')->groupby('parties_district');
        $query = (new Query())->select(['tsell.district as district','tsell.totalsale as sell','coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection'])->from(['tsell'=> $subQuery2])->leftJoin(['tcollection' => $subQuery3],'tcollection.parties_district = tsell.district');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [yii2's docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) you're using an `ActiveDataProvider` with an `ActiveRecord` inside. Here's [the example docs page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html) for your case.

I think what you want to do is to `return $dataProvider->getModels()` rather than just `return $dataProvider`. This will return presumably all rows, since I don't see a pagination mechanism (there could be a default pagination count).

For sorting, you could try sorting on the `$query` rather than the `$dataProvider`. Try something like:

```
$query->orderBy([
    'tsell.sell' => SORT_ASC
]);
```

Comment: I've added your solution for the sorting and return $dataProvider->getModels() . But it's not making any difference.

Comment: Well; without some more info that's all I can do. Sorry :( How about updating the question with some debugging information? How are you testing this? It's really hard to answer your question as it is; that's why no one answered so far.

Comment: There is no error actually. When I'm clicking on the the column heading A-Z or Z-A is showing just beside the heading but the data is not sorting. And whatever I search in the filterbox it's not filtering. Please tell me what information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a grid view with a data provider and filter model.

In your view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'parties_partyname', 
        'address', 
        'parties_district', 
        'name_manager', 
        'transport', 
        'dlno', 
        'instruction', 
        'con', 
        'district',
        'sale',
        'sell',
        'collection'
    ]
]); ?>
```

In your controller (replace index with the name of your view file):

```
$searchModel = new \frontend\modules\districtreport\models\PartiesSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Try removing `$dataProvider->setSort()` from your search model.

Also, in your detail of your gridview you are using the same variable name for both search models and data providers. They are two separate models so the variables should not be the same.

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\districtreport\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Bills;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Payment;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;

/**
 * PartiesSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties`.
 */
class PartiesSearch extends Parties
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['party_id'], 'integer'],
            [['parties_partyname', 'address', 'parties_district', 'name_manager', 'transport', 'dlno', 'instruction', 'con', 'district','sale','sell','collection'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $sql = 'select
        tsell.district as district,
        tsell.totalsale as sell,
        coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection
        from
            (SELECT
                district,
                coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale
            FROM `districts`
            left join
                (SELECT
                    parties_district,
                    billdate,
                    sum(billamount) as sale
                FROM `bills`
                left join parties on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname
                group by parties_district) as sell
            on sell.parties_district = districts.district) as tsell
        left join
            (SELECT
                parties_district,
                payment_date,
                COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection
            FROM `payment`
            left join parties on payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname
            group by parties_district) as tcollection
               on tsell.district = tcollection.parties_district';
        $query = Parties::findBySql($sql);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'party_id' => $this->party_id,
            'parties_partyname' => $this->parties_partyname,
            'address' => $this->address,
            'parties_district' => $this->parties_district,
            'name_manager' => $this->name_manager,
            'transport' => $this->transport,
            'dlno' => $this->dlno,
            'instruction' => $this->instruction,
            'con' => $this->con,
            'sell' => $this->sell,
            'collection' => $this->collection,
            'district' => $this->district,
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Simplified Search Model that works for me:

```
<?php

namespace common\models\event;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Model;

class ModelSearch extends Model
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Model::find()->indexBy('id');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => false
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same. It's not sorting or filtering.

Comment: try removing `$dataProvider->setSort()` from your search model. I do not use that it my search model and it allows me to do search and sort. There may be a configuration issue inside of that, but it may not be necessary.

Comment: Can you use the code I'm using in your answer? I mean what exact changes are you recommending me to do in my code.

Comment: The only difference is that I do not have `setSort()`

Comment: I added a new version of yours in my format, I did also remove the `like`, once you get it working you can add those back in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112613/discussion-between-michael-st-clair-and-tanmay).

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone run into this issue all these years later: queries built with the findBySql method will be **sortable** (and pagination will work too, which doesn't with ActiveDataProvider + findBySql) if you pass them to an [ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider) instead of an ActiveDataProvider, like this:

```
$query = MyModel::findBySql("SELECT * FROM ...");
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $query->all(),
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'model_id',
            'model_name'
        ],
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'model_name' => SORT_ASC
        ]
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 30
    ]
]);
```

The traditional filtering methods won't work. From the [findBySql() docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#findBySql()-detail):

> Note that because the SQL statement is already specified, calling additional query modification methods (such as where(), order()) on the created yii\db\ActiveQuery instance will have no effect.

I've come up with a workaround, it requires slightly more work than using the interface methods, but for complex queries (which I assume is why you are trying to use findBySql) it works:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $this->load($params);

    $filters = [];

    if ($this->model_id) $filters[] = ' "table"."model_id" = '.$this->model_id.' ';
    if ($this->model_name) $filters[] = ' "table"."model_name" ILIKE \'%'.$this->model_name.'%\' ';

    // ugly ifs can be put into a foreach if you don't need to customize each condition too much

    $filterCondition = count($filters) > 0 ? ' AND ' . implode(' AND ', $filters) : ' ';

    $query = MyModel::findBySql(
        // your query here
        .$filterCondition.
        // group by, order by etc.
    );

    // assemble the ArrayDataProvider (see above)

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

*Yii version: 2.0.34, PHP version: 7.3.18, PostgreSQL version: 12.2*