# Yii2 translating findBySql query to QueryBuilder query

Tags: php, sql, oracle, gridview, yii2

I have the following query using findbysql:

```
$query = Users::findBySql('select a.user_id, a.last_name,a.first_name, a.emp_id, ar.role_id from auth_users a, auth_user_roles AR, AUTH_USER_DEPTS AD, DEPARTMENTS D 
                where AD.DEPT_ID = D.DEPT_ID AND AR.USER_ID = AD.USER_ID and a.user_id = ar.user_id
                AND D.DEPT_GROUP_ID = :dept_group_id AND (ACCESS_END_DATE > SYSDATE OR ACCESS_END_DATE IS NULL)
                UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id, a.last_name, a.first_name, a.emp_id, NULL AS role_id FROM auth_users a, AUTH_USER_ROLES AR, AUTH_USER_DEPTS AD, DEPARTMENTS D
                WHERE AD.DEPT_ID = D.DEPT_ID AND AR.USER_ID = AD.USER_ID and a.user_id = ar.user_id 
                AND D.DEPT_GROUP_ID = :dept_group_id AND
                AR.ACCESS_END_DATE < SYSDATE AND AR.USER_ID NOT IN (select USER_ID from auth_user_roles where ACCESS_END_DATE > SYSDATE OR ACCESS_END_DATE IS NULL)', [':dept_group_id' => $dept_group_id ]);
```

This query does exactly what I want it to, but the problem is when I try to put it into a gridview it does not sort. According to [Sort and search column when I'm querying with findbysql in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042129/sort-and-search-column-when-im-querying-with-findbysql-in-yii2) it seems like I need to use query builder instead.

So I was trying to do that with the first part of my query (before the union), and it looks like so:

```
    $query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'emp_id'])
        ->from('AUTH_USERS');
    $query2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('USER_ID')
        ->from('AUTH_USER_ROLES')
        ->where('ACCESS_END_DATE>SYSDATE OR ACCESS_END_DATE IS NULL');
    $query = $query1->innerJoin('AUTH_USER_DEPTS', 'AUTH_USER_DEPTS.user_id = AUTH_USERS.user_id')->innerJoin('DEPARTMENTS', 'AUTH_USER_DEPTS.dept_id = DEPARTMENTS.dept_id');
   $query->innerJoin('AUTH_USER_ROLES', 'AUTH_USER_ROLES.USER_ID = auth_users.USER_ID')->where('ACCESS_END_DATE>SYSDATE OR ACCESS_END_DATE IS NULL');
```

However, my query comes out like this in yii and apparently oracle is not accepting the double quotes around the column names:

```
SELECT "user_id", "last_name", "first_name", "emp_id" FROM "AUTH_USERS" 
INNER JOIN "AUTH_USER_DEPTS" ON AUTH_USER_DEPTS.user_id = AUTH_USERS.user_id
INNER JOIN "DEPARTMENTS" ON AUTH_USER_DEPTS.dept_id = DEPARTMENTS.dept_id
INNER JOIN "AUTH_USER_ROLES" ON AUTH_USER_ROLES.USER_ID = auth_users.USER_ID 
WHERE ACCESS_END_DATE>SYSDATE OR ACCESS_END_DATE IS NULL
```

I know the query might be incorrect here already but I cant even get the double quotes to go away. Tried defining the select statements multiple ways suggested by the yii docs already with no success:

```
select(['user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'emp_id'])
select('user_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'emp_id')
select("user_id, last_name,first_name,emp_id")
```

I have also tried joining the queries like this from the docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

```
$query = $query1->innerJoin(['u' => $query2], 'u.user_id = user_id');
```

but it also complains that it doesnèt recognize u and the query instead comes out like so in yii:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "AUTH_USERS" INNER JOIN "AUTH_USER_DEPTS" ON AUTH_USER_DEPTS.user_id = AUTH_USERS.user_id INNER JOIN "DEPARTMENTS" ON AUTH_USER_DEPTS.dept_id = DEPARTMENTS.dept_id INNER JOIN (SELECT "USER_ID" FROM "AUTH_USER_ROLES" WHERE ACCESS_END_DATE>SYSDATE OR ACCESS_END_DATE IS NULL) "u" ON u.user_id = auth_users.user_id
```

At this point im just looking for the easiest way to build this query (whether it be using querybuilder or some other way) so that I can pass the query to my gridview and sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you first create all the data models you need from the tables you need for the query, using Gii it should be easy and it even creates the relationships you will need.

After that, you can do something like the following:

```
$query = Users::find()
    ->joinWith('theRelation1Name')
    ->joinWith('theRelation2Name')
    ->joinWith('theRelation3Name')
    ...
```

This way you don't need to give tables aliases or add the conditions needed for the relations to work.

Comment: Seems like ordering any query with unions is broken right now: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12968 Ended up just splitting into 2 separate queries and selecting one to pass into the gridview based off some criteria in the view